# как сделать иконку сайта?

Tags: html5, favicon

Подскажите пожалуйста!пробую все в точности как с видеоролика о том как сделать иконку для сайта,но ничего не работает

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        |<title> hi dude</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" type="images/x-icon" href="favicons/phone.ico">
    </head>
```

картинка 32pх

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть папку в которой лежит иконка в формате .ico
но все равно ничего не отображается

Comment: `images/x-icon` — прямо так в ролике и написано буква в букву?

Comment: нет!поменял на `image/x-icon` но все равно не работает)и разве  `image/x-icon` это не просто текст для большего понимания что за тип?разве я не могу написать в type любые символы?

Comment: Может ваш браузер не поддерживает формат .ico? Попробуй изменить тип иконки и путь к ней в теге <link> перед favicons ставь /

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin не помогло!скачал изображение в .png формате Вот код `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicons/coat_of_arms_trident_shield_icon_218780.png">`

Comment: `href="/favicons/coat_of_arms_trident_shield_icon_218780.png"` попробуй на это заменить тег href

Comment: @IrshatKhuzin к сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно положить файл с иконкой для сайта в корневой каталог, а не в отдельную папку, как у Вас на скриншоте.
Ничего дополнительно в коде прописывать не нужно - так делали на заре времен, сейчас хостинг умный и сам поймет, что это иконка.
если очень хотите в код что-то добавить, то сделайте так как на скриншоте (и тогда оставьте иконку в папке):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]